# webgl colors and alpha

Tags: javascript, webgl

I have a problem with colors and alpha in webgl.

A part of my JavaScript-Program:

```
gl.clearColor(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0); 
gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | gl.DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
```

And my fragment-shader:

```
precision highp float;
void main(void)
{
   float c = 0.5;
   float a = 0.7;
   if(gl_FragCoord.x < 310.0) // left color
      gl_FragColor = vec4(c, c, c, 1.0);
   else if(gl_FragCoord.x > 330.0) // right color
      gl_FragColor = vec4(c, c , c , a);
   else gl_FragColor = vec4(c / a, c / a, c / a, 1.0); // middle color
}
```

I am rendering a cube.

But unfortunatelly the cube is rendered in 3 different colors. The result:

image see http://fs5.directupload.net/images/160301/hcrpgyc9.png

The first gl_FragColor-command has an alpha = 1.0. The color is rendered as expected.

The second gl_FragColor-command has an alpha-value of 0.7.

The last parameter of the third gl_FragColor-command is again 1.0. r, g and b are divided by the alpha-value of 0.7. But I would like, that this command produces the same color as the second gl_FragColor-command. It seems, that my calculations are wrong. What can I do, to get the same color?

Tested with chrome and firefox, both on windows.

Comment: Could you please give us a working code snippet / jsfiddle? I don't get the same color on the right.

Comment: you can use http://www.mathematik.uni-marburg.de/~thormae/lectures/graphics1/code/WebGLShaderLightMat/ShaderLightMat.html

copy my fragment-shader into the fragment-textarea and click the submit-button. There you can see 3 different color. But i would like, that the middle and the right colors are the same.

Comment: files:
html http://textuploader.com/5vr4o
javascript http://textuploader.com/5vr4a

Comment: @Tamas Hegedus Do you use a microsoft pc or an apple pc? Could this be a problem with operating system color tables?

Comment: OK I had a mistake, now I have the same colors as you

Comment: If you want more info here's several other Q&As that covered the same issue

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29217189/alpha-blending-in-webgl-works-not-correctly?rq=1

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35372291/alpha-rendering-difference-between-opengl-and-webgl?rq=1

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35441319/strange-behavior-of-alpha-without-blending-in-webgl?rq=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The result you get is because the browser blends in the background color behind the canvas. Try setting the background-color, and you get something like this:

[image: The right]

The blending equation by default is:

```
blendedColor = sourceColor + destinationColor * (1 - sourceAlpha)
```

So with a white background, `sourceColor = c = 0.5, sourceAlpha = a = 0.7, destinationColor = white = 1.0`, so `blendedColor = 0.8`

In this context dividing by alpha doesn't make much sense. To match the middle region, you could replicate the blending process above:

```
else gl_FragColor = vec4(vec3(c) + vec3(1.0) * (1.0 - a), 1.0); // middle color
```

Comment: That´s it. Thank you! :)